# Problem webscraping a html element using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to extract the names of the companies who offered their product/services in a gubernamental purchase, as well as other elements. (With the others there's no problem).

The elements appears inside a table with the `class="BusinessCardCompanyName"`.

The only thing that is strange with these elements is the `onclick` attribute. I am not able to extract the content if the element triggers an event.

[image]

**HTML for the first element**

```
<td class="BusinessCardContentCell">
  <a class="BusinessCardCompanyName Pointer" 
   onclick="createAndOpenSupportModal({modalId:'BusinessCardWindow996457837', showTitle: true, cssClass:'bModal VortalModalDialog', modalHeight:600, modalWidth:1000, supportOptions: {windowURL: 'https://comunidad.comprasdominicana.gob.do/Directory/CompanyProfiles/DynamicMyCompanyProfile/ViewProfile?CompanyCode=700644024&amp;isConfirmRegistration=true' + '&amp;' + 'isModal=' + 'true' + '&amp;asPopupView=true', modalOptions: {scrollBar: false, escClose: false, modalClose: true, iframeScrollbar: true, closeClass: 'bClose'}, windowName: 'BusinessCardWindow996457837_iframe'}});"
>Guival Medical, SRL</a>
<br>
<br>
<span class="BusinessCardText"></span>
<div title="No hay datos suficientes para mostrar una clasificación de esta entidad" name="VB_">
<img src="https://comunidad.comprasdominicana.gob.do/StaticContent/Images/empty_star.png_v636868517519279829" height="15">
<img src="https://comunidad.comprasdominicana.gob.do/StaticContent/Images/empty_star.png_v636868517519279829" height="15">
<img src="https://comunidad.comprasdominicana.gob.do/StaticContent/Images/empty_star.png_v636868517519279829" height="15">
<img src="https://comunidad.comprasdominicana.gob.do/StaticContent/Images/empty_star.png_v636868517519279829" height="15">
<img src="https://comunidad.comprasdominicana.gob.do/StaticContent/Images/empty_star.png_v636868517519279829" height="15">
</div>
</td>
```

So far I tried using different selectors in `html_nodes()` like: `.BusinessCardCompanyName`, `.BusinessCardContentCell a`, etc.

**Code**

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://comunidad.comprasdominicana.gob.do//Public/Tendering/OpportunityDetail/Index?noticeUID=DO1.NTC.700904"

read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(".BusinessCardCompanyName") %>%
  html_text()
```

**Code that works**

```
read_html(url) %>%
    html_nodes("#cbxBasePriceValue") %>% 
    html_text() %>% 
    readr::parse_number()
```

Comment: Maybe paste in an example html that you get back from the url? So we can see what might be selectable

Answer (score 2):

This page does use some javascript to render the page thus rvest may not be the best tool depending on the information you are looking for.
I am was able to extract some information out. This might provide you as a starting point.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://comunidad.comprasdominicana.gob.do//Public/Tendering/OpportunityDetail/Index?noticeUID=DO1.NTC.700904"

#read the page
page <- read_html(url) 

#collect the business cards
businesscards <- page %>% html_nodes("table.VortalGrid[id=grdBiddersList_tbl]") %>% html_table(fill=TRUE)
supplier <- businesscards[[1]]$Supplier

#Extract the URL from the lines
supplier <- gsub(".+\\(\'(.*)\', .+", "\\1", supplier)
#remove blank URL
supplier <- supplier[nchar(supplier) >10 & !is.na(supplier)]

#reading supplier #2 as example
bc1 <-read_html(supplier[2])
bc1 %>% html_node("table") %>% html_table()
#most additional information is stored as attributes
```